# SQL Replace with new data

Tags: sql-server

I want to replace data in a field with new data that has a URL and also add two other fields from the table. So far I have:

```
(replace([DBS_Cert],'pres://Default.STAFFMANAGEMENT/STAFF/',''))
```

This produces the file name i.e certificate.pdf

What I need is the field with the result to be:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Certificates/[ColumnField]/[ColumnField]/certificate.pdf
```

I can't figure out how to make add the URL and Column Fields into `(replace([DBS_Cert],'pres://Default.STAFFMANAGEMENT/STAFF/',''))`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am using MS SQL. Thanks Andrew

Comment: What are the names of the ColumnField[0] and ColumnField[1]?  Can you share some more insight into the database table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate strings using '+'. And don't forget to convert types of your ColumnFields to varchar.

```
replace([DBS_Cert],
'pres://Default.STAFFMANAGEMENT/STAFF/',
'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Certificates/' + 
    CAST([ColumnField] as varchar(500)) + '/' + 
    CAST([ColumnField] as varchar(500)) + '/certificate.pdf')
```